# PDF library on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader, pdf-viewer

I do a research to search open source PDF library on Android. I want a LGPL library.

I find some examples like

- PDF-Renderer
- PDFBox
- gnujpdf
- PoDoFo

I want the library which can edit, read , search text in the modern PDF file.

Can they finish these tasks? Or, is there any other alternative?

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you tried to use podofo library? I know, that on ios platform it works quite well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example.Here you can able to Read,Search,Zoom in/out a Pdf-Files from SDCARD by using  jar file[Sample-code](https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library)

Comment: Does the project build in LGPL??

Comment: Yes it has been built under LGPL licence only..

Comment: by this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/andpdf/ , it says that 
GNU General Public License (GPL), GNU Library or Lesser General Public License (LGPL). It seems not only LGPL.

Comment: can this project search keywords?

Comment: Yes!! it will search your keywords.. try this

Comment: @king Wu.. yep!! its wrking like a charm

Comment: but, the version of iText is very old. The updated function cannot be used in Android

Comment: you can use openSource Pdf-reader(android) from google.code. There you can find many updated Sources for PdfReader

Comment: @Michael-aes I have downloaded from GIT but build failed. Showing nullPointerException

Comment: can anyone let me know how to enable search after integrating the libray which michael suggested ? I don't see option to search in that library. it shows only left / right / next etc but no search.